# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, geolocation

I am trying to use function below in chrome extension:

```
    function findMe(){
    if( navigator.geolocation ){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(alert("YES"), alert("NO"));
    }
}
```

And I get alert "NO", getCurrentPosition dosen't working, how to solve it?

Comment: See my answer at this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386996/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-not-updating-in-chrome-mobile/17540468#17540468

Answer (score 1):

getCurrentPosition() accepts 2 arguments, which MUST be functions. So you should pass functions as arguments.

The working code:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    console.log(position);
}, function(positionError) {
    console.error(positionError);
});
```

See also: http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html

Comment: and BTW there's a chrome permission "geolocation" which will return user's geolocation without asking for user's permission.