# navigator geolocation getCurrentPosition not working

Tags: javascript, android, html, geolocation, geo

I have this html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Geolocation test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            alert(position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude);
        }, function (error) {
            alert(error.code);
        }, {enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 0});
    </script>
</body>
```

Works on:

- Samsung Galaxy 3 Google Chrome
- Samsung Galaxy 3 native web browser
- Chrome Desktop.

Doesnt works on:

- Samsung Galaxy S2 Chrome
- Samsung Galaxy S2 native
- Firefox in desktop

I´ve been reading a lot of questions about this issue, but all of them says sometimes the position is unavailable or may be take a long time to retrieve it, but when I open the android maps app, it shows a perfect location immediately (even if I dont use it for a while)

I know I can use the timeout option to handle the error callback, but thats not a solution for me.

Thanks!

Comment: seems to be related to [Cordova 3.1 and Phone Gap Geolocation fails with “Position retrieval timed out” on Android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567798/cordova-3-1-and-phone-gap-geolocation-fails-with-position-retrieval-timed-out

Comment: Refer to Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386996/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-not-updating-in-chrome-mobile/54470936#54470936

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to problems of application permissions

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142065?hl=en